Using the same random variable multiple times in an expression
If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ with $X$ and $Y$ independent, we would say that $(X+Y) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 2)$ and $2X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 4)$.
But would $(X+X) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 2)$ or $\mathcal{N}(0, 4)$? In other words, would both $X$'s in the expression realize the same value, or would they only be drawn from the same distribution?
It seems confusing to me because if we only provide the distribution of $X$, it would seem the two appearances of $X$ would imply two different numbers drawn from the distribution of $X$. But if we associate $X$ with the result of an experiment like "What number is in the box?", it seems both $X$'s must be the same number we just don't know yet.

In $X + X$ both copies of $X$ are equal. Similarly, if $X$ and $Y$ are correlated then $X+Y$ refers to correlated samples of $X$ and $Y$. Formally, $X$ is a map from the probability space $\Omega$ to $\mathbb R$ and $X + X$ is simply a shortcut for $X(\omega) + X(\omega)$.

It is totally wrong to say that  If $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ and $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then $(X+Y) \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 2)$ . $Y=-X$ is a  counter-example.

@geetha290krm, thanks, updated question

The notation "$X+X$", when $X$ is a random variable, is total trash, and nobody uses it unless they are trying to cleverly catch people out on an exam. You should instead write "$X_1+X_2$, where $X_1,X_2$ are independent identically distributed (i.i.d.) random variables", or "$2X$", depending on which one you intend.
Please see this answer or this answer for further explanation.
Also, note that your comment about the interpretation of $X+Y$ is not necessarily correct, as you have not told us if $X$ and $Y$ are independent or not, and what the nature of the dependence is if they are dependent. Don't feel too bad about this, as most texts and instructors are bad at being explicit about this, and will often just plunge in with one assumption in the background, and leave it up to the student to figure out what it is.

I probably should feel bad leaving it out given how many stats classes I've taken. It recently occurred to me that I'd never really seen "$X+X$" used and wondered what it would be due to the ambiguity but I agree that it is bad notation.

Don't feel too bad. You can check the date on that second answer, and realize it took me four years and answering multiple questions to understand and resolve the confusion it causes.
